# Log4net AdoNetAppender Rolling table

Tags: .net-core, log4net

I am using MicroKnights.Logging.AdoNetAppender for my .Net core 3.1 application.
I want rolling table name for log table (new table for every month's logs).

Is there any possibilities to achieve this by making any changes in log4net.config file?

My log4net.config looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Log\logs_" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="MicroKnights.Logging.AdoNetAppender, MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5"/>
    <connectionStringName value="log4net" />
    <connectionStringFile value="appsettings.json" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO [Log_@TableName]
                           ([ApiName]
                           ,[RequestTimeUtc]
                           ,[TimeElapsed]
                           ,[Headers]
                           ,[Body]
                           ,[QueryString])
                     VALUES
                           (@ApiName
                           ,@RequestTimeUtc  
                           ,@TimeElapsed
                           ,@Headers
                           ,@Body
                           ,@QueryString)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@TableName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="10000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{TableName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ApiName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="10000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{ApiName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@RequestTimeUtc" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{RequestTimeUtc}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@TimeElapsed" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="10000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{TimeElapsed}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Headers" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="10000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{Headers}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Body" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="10000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{Body}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@QueryString" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="10000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{QueryString}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Executing Stored Procedure looks last option to me.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the config with

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO {0}
                           ([ApiName]
                           ,[RequestTimeUtc]
                           ,[TimeElapsed]
                           ,[Headers]
                           ,[Body]
                           ,[QueryString])
                     VALUES
                           (@ApiName
                           ,@RequestTimeUtc  
                           ,@TimeElapsed
                           ,@Headers
                           ,@Body
                           ,@QueryString)" />
```

And init log4net as follow:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> InitializeLog4Net()
     {
    var repository = LogManager.GetRepository(GetType().Assembly);

   
    ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConnectionString))
        throw new NullReferenceException($"Did not find the connectionString");

    var log4NetConfigFilename = $"Logging\\log4net.config";
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(log4NetConfigFilename);
    if (fileInfo.Exists == false)
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"Did not find log4net configuration file \"{log4NetConfigFilename}\"");

    XmlConfigurator.Configure(repository, fileInfo);

    if (repository.Configured == false)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Repository not configured");
    if (repository.ConfigurationMessages.Count != 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Repository messages found: {string.Join(",", repository.ConfigurationMessages)}");

    foreach (var appender in repository.GetAppenders())
    {
        if (appender is AdoNetAppender adoNetAppender)
        {
            adoNetAppender.CommandText = string.Format(adoNetAppender.CommandText, TableName);
            adoNetAppender.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            adoNetAppender.ErrorHandler = this;
            adoNetAppender.ActivateOptions();
        }
    }

   return _log4netErrors;
}
```

Generate problematically the TableName or take it from appsettings.json